# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2 on IIS error 502.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, preview

I use asp.net core 2 Preview 2.

I opened `stdoutLogEnabled = "true"` in `web.config` but the system does not write logs.

Deploying on windows server 2012 r2 gives :

**Error**

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure.

**Web.config**

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.WebHost.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

**Logs**

[image: image logs]

Please help me.

Comment: Do you use default web host setup?
Have you installed hosting bundle onto PC with IIS?

Comment: @Andril where is the hosting bundle for 2.0 preview?

Answer (score 16):

I had this same problem, even after installing the hosting bundle. The solution was in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) -

> Restart the system or execute `net stop was /y` followed by `net start w3svc` from a command prompt to pick up a change to the system PATH.

This is done after installing the .NET Core Windows server hosting bundle.

Comment: Help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try to install .NET Core SDK on the server:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

It solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

You need add this to your project :

```
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
```

Please view attached picture.

[image]

Comment: This didn't make a difference for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try using exact location of dotnet.exe in web.config 
`processPath="dotnet"`,
i.e. In my case C:\Program Files(x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Answer (score 2):

Brand new .net core 2.1  app trying to deploy to new Azure app service with new app service plan.  Same issues, namely 502.5 error ( HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure ).

I implemented the above steps and still ran into errors.  I opted to use the  chose the self-contained deployment mode (compared to framework dependent (win-x64)).

This resolved my issue.

This answer was also submitted to [question]: [.net-core-2.0 azure app service 502.5 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694286/net-core-2-0-azure-app-service-502-5-error/51064718#51064718)

*Perhaps these questions should be linked.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

You must install "Windows Hosting Bundle"

This is the newest version 2.1.0 and supports the old version

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem

I installed .NET Core 2.0 Preview 2 (the button in point 1) on the server
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#windowscmd

and it's running now

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurred then got resolved to follow below steps.

1: First delete .bin and.obj folder......mean Clean your application.

2: Definitely this is version mismatching issue to see this **>> go to "ASP.Net Core WebServer" in the Output window** to see action error.
In VS 2017, My case .
 2.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
AdminLTE> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
AdminLTE> The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.5' was not found.

3: Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 (for mine) through package manager console.

4: Rebuild again then issue got fixed.

Please reply if still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check the required dot net version, Confirm the same version applied in both server and developed local machine.
Using Command prompt :

```
>dotnet --info
```

Solution 2:

Execute the dll file using command prompt with dotnet interpreter

```
YOUR_DLL_PATH> dotnet yourdllpath.dll
```

By this you can find the actual error.

Good luck