# .net-core-2.0 azure app service 502.5 error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

Getting a 502.5 error after CI deployment to azure app service.

When running `dotnet {myproject}.dll` on the debug console this is the error I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
>      at My.IOEducation.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\home\site\repository\My.IOEducation.Api\Program.cs:line 11

Running `dotnet --version` returns `2.0.0`

Anyone else run into this yet and any suggestions on how to resolve?

UPDATE:
Here is the contents of the project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\Report\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\ExternalApis\" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\ExternalApis\Helpers\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\Dashboard\" />
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\Redis\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="PowerBI.NetStandard.Api" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="DataAccess\.DS_Store" />
    <None Remove=".DS_Store" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem locally at all? If so, can you reduce it to a minimal example? (I appreciate that if you can only reproduce it on Azure, that will make it very time consuming.) I've seen this problem before with System.Net.Http references... if you could include your project file, that would really help, even if you can't get to a minimal example.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue locally. It builds and runs fine in VS locally. I have seen the issue with System.Net.Http as well but was able to make that one happen locally in a different project. I will update the question with the project file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the issue. Let me start by adding a little more information. This was originally a .net-core-1.1 project that I updated to 2.0 following instructions provided by Microsoft. After upgrading, I had no issues at all running locally, but once I tried to publish my azure app service, i kept getting the IIS error. Last ditch effort was to create a new .net-core-2.0 project from scratch this morning and noticed that the new project file contained this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I added that to my existing project file (the one upgraded from 1.1) and now the error is gone and issue resolved.

Comment: Note that the [1.1 to 2.0 migration doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/) does mention adding this line (in the 'Update .NET Core CLI tools' section). But yes, the error is not helpful...

Answer (score 25):

I spoke to the aspnet IISIntegration team members and found my solution.

tldr: Empty out your wwwroot folder on kudu.

The issue relates to having old things leftover from previous 1.x deployments

**Step 1:**

Navigate to the Kudu Console (https://{yourapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/)

**Step 2:**

[image: Navigate to file structure]

**Step 3:**

[image: Delete wwwroot folder]

(Note: navigate into the "site" directory)

(Note: there is a wwwroot folder within this wwwroot. You should delete the one that is in the "site" directory)

**Step 4:**

Add a new empty folder called wwwroot where you just deleted the previous one (within "site" directory)

(Note: my deployment failed when I didn't have the empty wwwroot folder in there)

**Step 5:** Redeploy your app and hopefully it works. Good luck

Comment: I had to do this and the answer suggested by ktice12 to get ours working. Additionally, the app had to be stopped to delete the wwwroot folder.

Comment: Great answer. Tnx

Comment: The is the real work solution. the previous one is mentioned in the migration guide from 1.1 to 2.0 on Microsoft docs site, so that should not be the failed reason.

Comment: And what if you never deployed a 1.1 and created a new 2.0 from VS projects offered? Changed nothing in code, deployed to Azure, 502.5 error?

Answer (score 1):

Brand new .net core 2.1  app trying to deploy to new Azure app service with new app service plan.  Same issues, namely 502.5 error ( HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure ).

I implemented the above steps and still ran into errors.  I opted to use the  chose the self-contained deployment mode (compared to framework dependent (win-x64)).

This resolved my issue.

This answer was also submitted to [question]: [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114166/asp-net-core-2-0-preview-2-on-iis-error-502-5)

*Perhaps these questions should be linked.*

Comment: this was my issue, just couldn't remember how to set it to self-contained, then finally remembered it's in the publish settings... once i did this, boom it worked.